# How to use GetViewProjMatrix().TransformVector(LineDirection) in UE4?

Tags: projection, unreal, screen, unreal-4

I try to project a 3D vector (a direction, not a position) in screen space, but it does not return satisfying results:

```
 FVector LineDirectionOnScreen = 
   EdMode->ViewMatrices.GetViewProjMatrix().TransformVector(LineDirection);
 FVector2D LineDirectionOnScreen2D(
   LineDirectionOnScreen.X * 0.5f * (float)EdMode->ViewRect.Width(), 
   LineDirectionOnScreen.Y * 0.5f * (float)EdMode->ViewRect.Height());
```

When `LineDirection` is (0,0,1) it always returns a something like (0,Y) (Y can be anything), no matter how the camera is rotated.

What is wrong with my code?